# How can I group and sum a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I've had a good hunt for some time and can't find a solution so asking here.

I have data like so:

```
Plan         | Quantity_y
Starter      | 1
Intermediate | 1
Intermediate | 1
Intermediate | 2
Intermediate | 1
Intermediate | 14
Intermediate | 1
Advanced     | 1
Advanced     | 1
Advanced     | 2
Advanced     | 1
Incredible   | 1
Incredible   | 1
Incredible   | 1
Incredible   | 1
Incredible   | 1
Incredible   | 2
Incredible   | 2
```

and I'd like it to group AND count the individual numbers like so:

```
Plan         | Quantity_y
Starter      | 1
Intermediate | 20
Advanced     | 5
Incredible   | 9
```

I've tried so many options but am having no luck at all.

I've tried doing an `iterrows()` as well as trying to assign a value by counting and returning the count via a `.apply()` function call.  I'm just not getting how I can group AND count the sum of the numbers in that group.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score -4):

```
df.groupby('Plan', sort=False).sum()
```

Comment: What the point of answering this many times duplicate?

Comment: This doesn't have the result I'm expecting in my original question.  Thank you for trying though.  This doesn't individually count the second column (Quantity_y) and group by the first (Plan).

Comment: I found it, it's the `.agg()` function.  Will add answer once the time has passed enough to allow me to.

Comment: only sum don need `agg` .  Do you see comment about why i posted answer not make duplicated? It rather disproves that code is correct. maybe your dataset is differ from example.  your dataset have many columns different from example. then use following : `df.groupby('Plan', sort=False)['Quantity_y'].sum()`